# Rename all files with different extensions to .txt in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to rename all files in a folder based on the extension. I want all files to be in `.txt` format. Files in the folder can be of different extension but I am trying to have them all renamed to `.txt`.

I tried to do the below

```
allFiles = 'Path where the files are located'
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(allFiles, '*.0000')):
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-5] + '.txt')
```

The above throws an error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: I am curious why you would rename *any* file extension to .txt? It won't make them text files. (Is it some kind of prank?)

Comment: What determine the file type is it's contents not its name. Windows  trust on extension and spread this idea but the file is what it contents not how is named

Comment: You should include the full stack trace about where this error actually occurs.

Comment: You may consider accepting an answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
import os


def renameFilesToTxt(input_dir):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
        for name in files:
            filePath = os.path.join(path, name)
            target_filePath = ''.join(filePath.split('.')[:-1])+".txt"
            os.rename(filePath, target_filePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a script that will change your folder's all file extensions and the script is tested in my local pc.

In your desire folder run this script

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
items = os.listdir(".")

newlist = []
for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".0000"):
        newlist.append(names)

for i in newlist:
    print(i)
    p = Path(i)
    p.rename(p.with_suffix('.txt'))
```

[Note : THE SCRIPT IS TESTED AND ITS WORK]

Comment: Rather than that `newlist` code, it's much simpler to instead use glob() method: `for f in Path(".").glob("*.0000"):`.